# Why does my python 3 input requires quotes when i use the function

Tags: python

I am new to programming and i have a problem. When i use input function for my program, it wants me to enter my input with quotes. I am kind of sure that i am using python3 because other functions are running in the form of python3 codes.
For example my print function is working like:
print("Hello") instead of print "Hello"

I don't know what's wrong with input() function. Can someone please help me?

I am using MacOS version 10.14.6 and i am using SublimeText as my text editor

Update: I figured it out. Thank you all for answering. With the help of your answers i realized that i was using python 2.x. The problem was with my SublimeText build and i was able to find the problem!

Comment: when you don't enter the input with quote, do you get an error? if so, what's the error message?

Comment: And how do you implement the input() function?

Comment: @TobiasP.G. The `input()` function is builtin.

Comment: @TobiasP.G., it's built-in

Comment: Could you show us your code ? (the part with the `input()`)

Comment: Sorry if "implement" was the wrong word, what I wanted was more context, as in how the input() function is used in the script : )

Comment: That certainly sounds like you're using Python 2.x.  `print("Hello")` proves nothing, that has always worked (the parentheses just weren't necessary).  Try `raw_input()`, that's the 2.x solution, and if it works it proves you're not using 3.x.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Now i figured out that i am actually using python 2.7. Now my new question is i have python 3.8 downloaded on my macbook, how can i change my default python version to python3? PS: In my sublime text build python3 is targeted as source with the line "selector": "source.python3", But still it is working on python 2.x i would like to know why.

Comment: Please accept the answer you find suitable

Comment: @Tugra You just have to override Python2 as being default.

Hope this article helps you  https://dev.to/malwarebo/how-to-set-python3-as-a-default-python-version-on-mac-4jjf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error only occur in py2 which is why I believe you are making use of Python 2.
Try using `raw_input()`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, you take input using `input()` function. By default, when you provide any input to Python 3 using `input()` method it will consider it of type `String`. If you want to take an `Integer` as input you need to mention `int(input())` and then by using `type()` method you can check its type.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i'm understand correctly , but `input()` is built-in function 
.For example to use it:

```
var1 = input("Please enter anything: ")
print(var1)
```

output:

```
Please enter anything: our answer is here
our answer is here
```